# What increases faster: $(\log n)^2$ or $n^{1/3} + \log n$

Tags: number-theory

What increases faster: $(\log n)^2$ or $n^{1/3} + \log n$ and why? And also, what increases faster $\log n$ or $n^{x}$, where $x$ is a random positive constant number?

Comment: $n^x$ increases faster than $(logn)^y,$where $x>0,y>0.$

Comment: @Hecke how can I prove it?

Comment: @AndreiI: If you have calulus at your disposal, just compare the derivatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that:

> $$
> f(n)=O(g(n)) \iff \text{For some } C\ge0,\quad\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = C
> $$

Hence, $n^{1/3}+\log n$ grows faster (that is, we have $(\log n)^2 = O(n^{1/3}+\log n)$), since by L'Hôpital's Rule, we have:
$$ \begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{(\log n)^2}{n^{1/3}+\log n} &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{2\log n}{n}}{\dfrac{1}{3}n^{-2/3}+\dfrac{1}{n}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{2\log n}{\dfrac{1}{3}n^{1/3}+1}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{2}{n}}{\dfrac{1}{9}n^{-2/3}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{2}{\dfrac{1}{9}n^{1/3}}\\
&= 18\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^{1/3}}\\
&= 18(0)=0\ge0
\end{align*} $$

---

In general, notice that for any constant $x>0$, $n^x$ will grow faster than a logarithm (that is, $\log n = O(n^x)$), since:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\log n}{n^x} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{n}}{xn^{x-1}}= \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{xn^x}= \dfrac{1}{x}\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^x}= \dfrac{1}{x}(0)=0\ge0
$$

Comment: Nice indeed. +1

Answer (score 3):

Since both $\log n$ and $n^x\mapsto\infty$ when $n\mapsto\infty$, from [l'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule),

$$\lim_{n\to ∞}{\frac{\log n}{n^x}}
=\lim_{n\to ∞}{\frac{(\log n)^{'}}{(n^x)^{'}}}
=\lim_{n\to ∞}{\frac{1/n}{xn^{x-1}}}
=\lim_{n\to ∞}{\frac{1}{xn^x}}=0.$$

Comment: @DonAntonio OP says that $x$ is a random positive constant number,so $x>0.$

Comment: Indeed so, Hecke. +1

Answer (score 2):

For the second part of your question, recall that the log function is the inverse of the rapidly increasing exponential function. This graph shows that the exponential function does indeed increase faster.

[image]

Comment: $x$ in my problem is a constant and not a variable like in yours.

Comment: Ah, my apologies then. Typically x is a variable.